# Copy and Paste Files without FileUtil

Tags: file, copy, pascal, paste, lazarus

After browsing on the internet, I have discovered that the Free Pascal compiler Lazarus has a few issues with using the unit "FileUtil", which has the procedures that I need to copy and paste files.

So I thought that I could write procedure(s) that would do it for me.   I need the procedure(s) to select a file (of any kind, text, image, etc), to create a copy of the file (With a name like "FileName(Copy)"), and to place the copied file in a hard-coded folder, such as "\test". I'm having a bit of trouble, can anybody help out with code or even another library that can do the same as FileUtil?

I'm open to ideas as  my previous attempts have crashed and burned. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Which platforms are you going to target ?

Comment: Please describe the issues with fileutil

Comment: `FileUtil` has nothing to do with "Copy and Paste", which is a user interface action. Do you mean "copying a file"? What specific problem are you having with `CopyFile`? "I read somewhere on the internet it doesn't work" isn't a problem description, and it's pretty unlikely that you'll write a version yourself that's any better than the implementation they've written that's been tested by thousands of people (and used internally by the LCL).

Comment: Yes, subroutines in that unit are needed, but I can't get it to work.

Let me explain the problem:
The Unit "FileUtil" is in the LCL files of the compiler, but when told by a program to "use" it, it errors out and says "Fatal: component not found." I've looked around on various forum boards and it's apparently some sort of error with the LCL update. So, I tried uninstalling it and reinstalling an older version, and it still doesnt work. I tried rebuilding the LCL folder and cleaning/debugging it - still nothing. I wanted to know if anybody has another procedure which could be used to help me?

Comment: @Tlama Also, I plan to target mainly encrypted files such as .bin and .sql files. It's not really a massive problem as it stands, I'm just trying to see if I can make my own backup system.